# Enable HTTPS for a web service

Tags: website, https

I have a web application that currently handles HTTP traffic only.  What are the generic steps to be followed to make my service handle HTTPS?

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain an SSL certificate and then tell any program you want to use HTTPS with to use that certificate for its secure connections.

You have three general options for getting a certificate:

1. You can buy a certificate from a third party.
2. You can obtain a certificate for free from a third party.
3. You can generate a certificate yourself with software.

**Caveats**

1. Paid certificates cost money and typically don't offer anything beyond what a free certificate might.
2. Free third party certificates may have certain conditions or limitations. For instance, [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) is a good option for free certificates. However, you will need to renew any Let's Encrypt certificate you obtain once every three months (which is simple, but this isn't necessarily a requirement with other certificates).
3. So-called *self-signed certificates* (those you generate yourself) aren't trusted by major web browsers and will typically cause a warning to be served stating that the certificate is untrusted and users will be encouraged away from your site or application. Users can often override these warnings but they make these certificates more suitable for testing or for use with applications that often really don't care about checking certificate validity (e.g. personal email servers or FTP).

---

*If you do go with Let's Encrypt, you should probably have a look at [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/) (Linux, etc.) or [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) (Windows) for ACME applications to run on your server.*

---